# Python/Kivy : Can i call function on double click on Label

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Can someone tell me how to call function `def demo()` on double click of Label `Item1`,`Item2` ?

## test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

def convert_data(data):
    l = []
    for item in data:
        for key, value in item.items():
            l.append({'text': key, 'value': value})
    return l

class test():

    def demo(self):
        print('Demo')

class Invoice(Screen):
    def abc(self):
        arr = ({'Item1': ''},{'Item2': 1000})

        self.rv.data = convert_data(arr)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

<Label@Label>:
    font_size: 15
    size_hint_y:None
    height: 30

<Item@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    text: ""
    value: 0
    padding : 5, 0
    spacing: 10, 0
    Label:
        size_hint_x: .35
        text: root.text
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .6, .6, .6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        size_hint_x: .15
        text: str(root.value)
        halign: 'right'
        valign: 'middle'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .6, .6, .6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

Invoice:
    rv: rv
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 15, 15

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding : 5, 5
            size_hint: .6, None
            pos_hint: {'x': .18,}


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                padding : 5, 5
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 800, 40
                size_hint: 1, None

                Button:
                    text: "Show"
                    size_hint_x: .05
                    spacing_x: 30
                    on_press:root.abc()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, 1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: .5, 1
                padding : 0, 15
                spacing: 10, 10
                size: 500, 30


                BoxLayout:
                    RecycleView:
                        id: rv
                        viewclass: 'Item'
                        RecycleBoxLayout:
                            default_size: None, dp(30)
                            default_size_hint: 1, None
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a subclass of your Label and attach the double_tap event to it

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            demo()
```

Comment: Can you give me one more favour?When i double click(`touch.is_double_tap:`) then it calls `demo()` function many time.How to call it only once?

Comment: refer to the docs on how to do implement other features, you can do this by adding `double_tap_time = 1` as part of the arguments

Comment: @Joeydanieldarko - hi, I copy/pasted your code onto a file I was playing with. The one hitch I found is that demo() is called no matter where on the screen I double click. Did I miss something?

Comment: I guess you have to look at the collide_points of the touch and run the demo() on the needed parent